# KivyMD BottomNavigation with different .kv files

Tags: python, kivymd

Im working on an mobile calculator app. Please be aware that this is my first own project.
The app should be able to offer a simple calc advanceded and should display different functions.
I achive this with the BottomNavigation but the file gets huge. Any troubleshooting is not possible at least not for me.
with the screenmanager I could separate the different screens into different files but I cannot do this BottomNavigator.
Could Anybody give me a hint please.

working with the screenmanager

Answer (score 0):

found it just in case anybody doesnt know either:

```
#main.py
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivymd.uix.bottomnavigation.bottomnavigation import MDBottomNavigationItem

class MainApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Dark"
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "BlueGray"

        return Builder.load_file("my.kv")

MainApp().run()
```

#my.kv

```
#:include advanced_calc_screen.kv

BoxLayout:
    orientation: "vertical"


        MDBottomNavigationItem:
            name: "advanced_calc"
            text: "advanced"

            icon: "calculator"
            Advanced:
```

#advanced_calc_screen.kv

```
 <Advanced>:

    Button:
        text: "You are at Homescreen"
```